# Mulitple vimrc-files, multiple vim-directories.

Tags: vim

I'm trying to get better with Vim at Ubuntu 14.04, but I struggle to understand it's structure. I've been Googling around for quite some time, but this questions I haven't gotten answered anywhere.

I'm trying to install some plugins and make a good .vimrc-file for myself, in the future. But when I have to install plugins, then the Readme-files tell me, to put the files in the 'plugin'-directory in the vim-folder. But I've discovered that I have two vim-folders:
 - One in /etc/vim/
 - and one in ~/.vim/
I tried putting the plugin in each folder, and it worked, in the latter one. But I don't understand why. Can anyone explain it?

And it's the same thing for the vimrc-file. If I run a :version in vim, then I get, that there's a vimrc-file here /etc/vim/vimrc and theres one here ~/.vimrc   . Now - why is one hidden and one is not? I'm a Windows-kid originally, and if confuses me, because it looks like that the format is different, from one file to the next. But mainly; where is it good manners to insert the custom changes to the vimrc-file? For the system-vimrc file, or for the user I'm using?

Comment: Usually the /etc version is created on Vim Install and sets default options that are updated / modified by the local version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files and directories under `/etc/vim/` make up Vim's system-wide runtime files.

***You must never touch them.***

- because they will be overwritten next time you update Vim,
- because messing with them puts Vim in an unstable state,
- because you need to escalate privileges.

All *your* configuration must happen in *your* `$HOME`:

- *your* settings/mappings go into `~/.vimrc`,
- *your* plugins and colorschemes and anything you download from third parties go into `~/.vim/`.

That said, most (all?) plugins clearly use `~/.vim` and `~/.vimrc` or their `$HOME` variants in their install instructions. If they don't, complain to their author.

Comment: 'You must never touch them' ... You scared me now, man. How will I be able to sleep at night, now!? ;-)

Comment: Well, that was kind of the point. I've heard about an old woman in the Arkham asylum whom keeps warning people against what she calls "the hidden fourth bullet point"… nah, she's just mad, isn't she? There are *only* three bullet points, right? Hmm… right?